# Solidity - Check balance of a user address using openzeppelin

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I'm using `Truffle` and `upgradable Openzeppelin contracts`. I have two contracts.

**Token.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract MyToken is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable {
    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() initializer {}

    function initialize() initializer public {
        __ERC20_init("MyToken", "MTK");

        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

**AnotherContract.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
import "./IAnotherContract.sol";

contract AnotherContract is IAnotherContract {
  function doSomethingIfBalanceIsEnough()
    external
    returns (string memory)
  {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

How do I check how many `MTK` tokens a user has? I need to check it in `doSomethingIfBalanceIsEnough` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token contract [implements](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/v4.5.1/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol#L106) a `balanceOf()` function that returns token balance of an address.

You can make an external call from `AnotherContract` to `MyToken` address, invoking its `balanceOf()` function, passing it the user's address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
import "./IAnotherContract.sol";

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract AnotherContract is IAnotherContract {
    function doSomethingIfBalanceIsEnough()
      external
      returns (string memory)
    {
        uint256 userBalance = IERC20(myTokenAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender);
        if (userBalance > 0) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to use ```"@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/IERC20Upgradeable.sol"``` For upgradable erc20?

Comment: @MiladJafari The custom interface is sufficient, but you can use the `IERC20Upgradeable` instead as well.